# By which means a form should be made to make it mobile friendly in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-form, list-form

By which means a form should be made to make it mobile friendly in sharepoint, so that i can pass the link in an mobile app and it remains responsive. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You may want to investigate Formotus.  Any of your InfoPath forms can be easily converted into mobile forms that run on any mobile device and also work offline.

Comment: I dont think something licence one we need for our organisation, any OOB methods or softwares similar to designer infopath.